# Magento - Different image gallery block for specific products or categories

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying to change how the image gallery is displayed but only for specific products or specific categories. Using the developer display hints, I can see that the block I want to modify for certain products is output by media.phtml.

Suppose I have an alternate file called media-special.phtml, what XML do I need to use and where do I put that XML, to use media-special.phtml instead of media.phtml for specific products or specific categories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both categories and products allow you to save layout xml along with the entity record. In this field for the desired entities, add the following:

```
<action method="setTemplate" block="product.info.media">
    <tpl>path/to/media-special.phtml</tpl>
</action>
```

Comment: Thanks, one more question if you can please -- how did you find block="product.info.media"? Now I have the same problem trying to change other blocks with a custom .phtml file, where do you find the name of the block?

Comment: Turn on template path hints and search for the template names in layout XML, or (BETTER!) I recommend [Fabrizio Branca's Advanced Template Path Hints 2.0](http://www.fabrizio-branca.de/magento-advanced-template-hints-20.html).